# Find the parameters provided to an unknown vectorized function

Tags: r

I am trying to create an scoring function (called `evalFunc`). To get a score I am trying to calculate the R-squared value of a generated model. How do I know how the values are being passed to 'evalFunc' from within the `rbga.bin` function?

```
library(genalg)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
df_factored<-data.frame(colA=runif(30),colB=runif(30),colC=runif(30),colD=runif(30))
dataset <- colnames(df_factored)[2:length(df_factored)]
chromosome = sample(c(0,1),length(dataset),replace=T)
#dataset[chromosome == 1]

evalFunc <- function(x) {
  #My end goal is to have the values passed into evalFunc be evaluated as the IV's in a linear model
  res<-summary(lm(as.numeric(colA)~x,
                  data=df_factored))$r.squared 
  return(res)
}

iter = 10
GAmodel <- rbga.bin(size = 2, popSize = 200, iters = iter, mutationChance = 0.01, elitism = T, evalFunc = evalFunc)
cat(summary(GAmodel))
```

Comment: but x is going to be a vector of length 2 with zero or 1 in your example? Do you want to use x to select which of colB, colC or colD are used in the regression?

Comment: yep, exactly. I assumed the parameters would be the colnames, but based on your comment they are not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the source by typing `rbga.bin`, but better than that you can run `debug(rbga.bin)`, then the next time you call that function, it allows you to step through the function.  In this case the first time you get to your function is in this line (approximately line 82 of the function):

```
                  evalVals[object] = evalFunc(population[object,
                    ])
```

At this point, `population` is 200x2 matrix consisting of 0s and 1s:

```
head(population)
# [1,]    0    1
# [2,]    0    1
# [3,]    0    1
# [4,]    1    0
# [5,]    0    1
# [6,]    1    0
```

And `object` is the number 1, so `population[object,]` is the vector `c(0,1)`.

When you've finished with `debug` you can `undebug(rbga.bin)` and it won't go into debug mode every time you call `rbga.bin`.